# Why do none of the function calls execute like they're supposed to within this program?

Tags: python, function

The title pretty much says it all. Each of the little functions works on their own (I tested them in separate files) , but they don't work when put into the main function. What am I doing wrong? (The codeblock is really long, sorry about that) 
The basic issue is that it doesn't move to executing the function when the option is selected, it just ends.

```
    from sys import exit

def readFrom():
    file = input('What file do you want to read from? (Please include extension)')
    try:
        infile = open(file, 'r')

        line = infile.readline()
        cleanLine = line.strip()

        while line != '':
            print(cleanLine)
            line = infile.readline()
            cleanLine = line.strip()
        infile.close()
        menu()
    except IOError:
        print('Sorry, that is not a valid file. It might not exist or might not be in the correct directory.')

def writeTest():
    file = input('What file do you want to write to?')
    outfile = open(file,'w')

    addition = input('What would you like to write to the file?')
    try:
        addition = int(addition)
    except:
        print('Sorry, that is invalid.')
        writeTest()
    outfile.write(str(addition))
    outfile.close()
    menu()

def fileAppend():
    outfile = open('example.txt','a')

    addition = input('What would you like to add to the file?')
    try:
        addition = int(addition)
    except:
        print('Sorry, that is invalid.')
        fileAppend()
    outfile.write(str(addition))
    outfile.close()
    menu()

def menu():
    print('Hello! Welcome to the file editing helper!')
    answer = input('Selection Menu:\n'
                '0. Exit\n'
                '1. Read from file\n'
                '2. Write integers to a file\n'
                '3. Append integers to a file\n'
                'Which would you like to do? ')

    if answer == 1:
        readFrom()
    if answer == 2:
        writeTest()
    if answer == 3:
        fileAppend()
    if answer == 0:
        exit()

menu()
```

I've tried it every way that I can think of, I've put the full functions into the segments where I'd otherwise call the functions, and if I didn't have to have them in functions per the requirements I've been given, I wouldn't have them in functions. Any tips are helpful because I am *really* bad at this.

Comment: It compiles just fine on my machine using python3. You have an indent in the first line that is questionable, is that the same exact way in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, in your menu() you ask for an input, you then compare that input against an integer, but your input is considered a string.

example:

```
user_input = input('Enter a number') # 7
```

user_input will be '7', not 7, so you can't say

```
if user_input == 7:
    #do this
```

because it never will. So here is your menu fixed.

```
def menu():
    print('Hello! Welcome to the file editing helper!')
    answer = int(input('Selection Menu:\n'
                '0. Exit\n'
                '1. Read from file\n'
                '2. Write integers to a file\n'
                '3. Append integers to a file\n'
                'Which would you like to do? '))

    if answer == 1:
        readFrom()
    if answer == 2:
        writeTest()
    if answer == 3:
        fileAppend()
    if answer == 0:
        exit()

menu()
```

I wrapped the input function in an int() method and that should work now. 
1 is not equal to '1', which is what you're trying to do.